# Terms clustering

Tags: python, string, data-structures

I have a list like this: list_1= [['Jhon', 'Rana'], ['Rana', 'Rana'], ['Rana', 'Zhang'], [['Jhon', 'Maria'], ['Jhon', 'Fabio'], [['Rana', 'Julia']]. And I have the following list containing the number of relations in each in each term of the previous onelist2: [Rana: 3, Jhon: 3, Zhang:1, Maria:1, Fabio:1, Julia:1]].

Now I want to create clusters of these terms starting with the one with the highest score, Rana for example: so for Rana I have the following structure {Rana : [Jhon, Zhang, Julia]} then as not all the terms in list 2 are covered I'm going to continue the work: so I'm going to work with Jhon and he has the following structure {Jhon : [Rana, Maria, Fabio]},

I'll finish here without continuing as all the terms are covered.

I have proposed this code but it does not give me the expected results.
Where list1 is the dictionary containing the main term (Rana or Jhon ) and its related terms, list2 contains the terms related to Rana or Jhon. list_1 and list2 are described above. converted_dict is list 2 sorted in descending order,

```
def myfun(myitem):
  test= True
  list1= {}
  list2 = []
  keys= myitem#
  print(keys)

  if keys not in list2 or keys not in list1:
    for sub in list_1:
      if (sub[0] == keys ):
        list2.append(sub[1])
      elif (sub[0] not in list2 ) :
          list2.append(sub[0])
      else:
        break
  list1.update({keys: list2})
  print(list1)

for i in list(converted_dict.keys()):
  myfun(i)
```

Giving a list of terms in a list I want to split them in groups:

Comment: Can you please provide an example of myitem and the results you're seeing with that input?